# How to check if url is manually typed in php

Tags: php, post, get

I need my visitors to visit my site (the login page, for example) through the navigation bar instead of manually typing the URL.

If they do type the URL, then an error message will be shown.

How should I check if they visit through a link instead of manual input.

Is it possible to check the request method, or does it only work for forms?

Comment: You can use `$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER];` but I doubt if it'll get better than that.

Comment: from the PHP manual: The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you COULD check is the referrer:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Though this isn't foolproof and you're never going to know for sure that a user actually typed it in (there is no way to do this).

Comment: I have seen code that check this by checking request method,so I am confused,only by typing URL,it will never send post to server,is that the same case that click the link I created for the visitor?

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the contents of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` (the spelling is correct) to see which page referred your visitor. It will be empty if your visitor typed the URL.

However, this is set by the user-agent (the browser), and is not guaranteed. You can't really trust it. I have to ask, though, why does it matter?

Comment: Weird, when I posted my answer (which is identical) yours wasn't here, sorry about that.

Comment: @garrettmurray Don't worry - we probably posted at roughly the same time.